# Acer C-7 Chrome Book

Tags: unity

I am running 12.04 Chrubutu and I like it.  However, I am running 13.04 on my other netbooks and laptops and I heard that 13.04 is supported on the chrome books.  I am would very much like to find out how to update my 12.04 Chrubuntu to 13.04.  Can someone lead me to a good source of instructions?  Thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

1. Open Update Manager
2. Check for updates. You should then see a notification telling you a new release is available at the top.
3. Click Upgrade
4. Follow the instructions you are given.